# Calculate the work for moist air adiabatic expansion and compression?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, adiabatic

( During expansion some water vapor condenses and is removed from the system. )

More details:

Initial conditions: t 25C, p 1013 mB, humidity 100%, 
then expansion to ~ <strike>450</strike> 540 mB
through the double chamber like this: [1drv.ms/u/s!AjD7S4pRBfU9oD6Ysv1qUhOxe9pb](http://1drv.ms/u/s!AjD7S4pRBfU9oD6Ysv1qUhOxe9pb)
I have the description of calculations for the first stage - expansion here:
[1drv.ms/w/s!AjD7S4pRBfU9oDz9lYlSudWLj93y](http://1drv.ms/w/s!AjD7S4pRBfU9oDz9lYlSudWLj93y)
but I do not see there the latent heat. I have no description of calculations for compression part.

Most basic question is: 
what will happen to latent heat energy after expansion - compression - will the air have the higher temperature after that?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89845/discussion-on-question-by-aleksey-calculate-the-work-for-moist-air-adiabatic-exp).

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the expansion takes place adiabatically and reversibly and that the change in enthalpy of the stream is counterbalanced by the change in kinetic energy of the stream.

For the adiabatic reversible expansion, the change in entropy per unit mass of the flowing stream is zero.  Take as a basis 1 lb of air (on a dry basis), initially at 1 Bar, 25 C, and 100% relative humidity.  The absolute humidity A represents the number of pounds of water vapor per pound of dry air in a stream.  For the inlet stream to the expansion section, $$A_{in}=\frac{18p^*(25)}{29(p_{in}-p^*(25))}\tag{1}$$where $p^*(25)$ represents the absolute vapor pressure of water at 25 C and $p_{in}$ is the inlet pressure (1013.5 mB). For the outlet stream from the expansion section, $$A_{out}=\frac{18p^*(T)}{29(p_{out}-p^*(T))}\tag{2}$$where $p_{out}=450\ mB$.  The amount of condensed water per pound of dry air is:  $$C=A_{in}-A_{out}\tag{3}$$
The change in partial mass entropy of the air (on a dry basis) is $$\Delta s_{air}=\left[C_{v, air}\ln{\left(\frac{T}{298}\right)}-R\ln{\left(\frac{(p_{out}-p^*(T))}{(p_{in}-p^*(25))}\right)}\right]/29\tag{4}$$The change in mass partial mass entropy of the water vapor is $$\Delta s_{vapor}=\left[C_{v, vapor}\ln{\left(\frac{T}{298}\right)}-R\ln{\left(\frac{p^*(T)}{p^*(25)}\right)}\right]/18\tag{5}$$The change in partial mass entropy of the water that becomes condensate is given by:
$$\Delta s_{cond}=\left[-\frac{[\Delta H_{vap}(25)]}{298}+C_{v,liq}\ln{\left(\frac{T}{298}\right)}\right]/18\tag{6}$$where $\Delta H_{vap}(25)$ is the molar heat of vaporization of water at 25 C.
If the expansion is assumed to be adiabatic and reversible, then $$\Delta s_{air}+A_{out}\Delta s_{vapor}+C\Delta s_{cond}=0\tag{7}$$
These equations would be solved simultaneously for the outlet temperature T.

Comment: Intuitively, 450 mB seems like a low enough pressure to reduce the temperature below 0 C.  This would result in ice rather than water.

Comment: Yes, indeed it should be 540 mB, I changed the description. Thank you for your formulas.